# How to clear background in QTreeView during item-edit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qtgui

Playing around with an editable `QAbstractItemModel`, I noticed that the old text is not deleted on edit and thus yields ugly overlay effects.

I can reproduce this with the [Editable Tree Model Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/itemviews-editabletreemodel.html) from Qt (click item, hit F2, hit End, hit backspace a few times). Below screenshot shows  an item during editing, the text 'with signals on' is already deleted. It is like an overlay. The old text is in the background (white on blue) and above that current text is on top (black on blue).

[image: QTreeView while deleting a suffix]

Same effect when deleting/inserting characters:

[image: QTreeView overlay during editing]

The screenshots are from a Fedora 19 system, running gnome shell. I can still reproduce this under Fedora 23.

Is this a bug in the default [style](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qstyle.html#details) used for gnome shell (style name: 'gtk+') or is it a packaging bug?

Can I work-around this?

When explicitly using another style (e.g. `./editabletreemodel -style windows` or `-style fusion`) the background is cleared correctly during editing.

Comment: I think, that the problem is that in your case, the `QLineEdit` has a transparent background. You can try setting a stylesheet like `QLineEdit{background-color: white;}`

Comment: @thuga, yes, that works. Post your comment as answer and I'll accept it. Very elegant work-around.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: See also QTBUG: [While editing an item in an itemview the old text stays visible in the background](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31509)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your case, the `QLineEdit` has a transparent background. You can try setting a stylesheet like `QLineEdit{background-color: white;}`.

Comment: Setting a stylesheet for a Qt application can easily be tested via the `-stylesheet FILENAME` option. For example: `echo QLineEdit, QDateTimeEdit {background-color: white;} > white.css ; ./editabletreemodel -stylesheet white.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Until the gtk+ Qt style is fixed, one can work around this with a style sheet like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyle>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  // ...
  if (QApplication::style()
      && QApplication::style()->objectName() == "gtk+"
      && qApp->styleSheet().isEmpty()) {
    qApp->setStyleSheet(
        "QLineEdit, QAbstractSpinBox {background-color:white;}");
  }
  // ...
}
```